# Node JS: Получить результат из БД MySQL в переменную

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback

Node JS: Есть необходимость получить JSON из DB MySQL в переменную, в console.log(grantRes) есть результат, а переменная res == undefined (нет JSON ).
Понимаю что ассинхроность, может callback не так написал. 
Просьба помочь:
Код:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host:'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password:'root',
  database:'testCRM',
  port:'3306'
});

var   doSQL = function (script, callback)  {
                  con.connect (function(err) {
                            if (err) throw err;  });
                  con.query(script, function (err, result) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            callback(result[0]);
                  con.end();
                            });
                                    }

var sproc = ( "CALL `getUsers` ('*');")

var res = doSQL  (sproc, async function(res){
              var grantRes = await JSON.stringify(res);
                  //console.log('grantRes is: ' + grantRes);
                  return grantRes;
              });
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, не, не дубликат. Он пытался, просто пару скобок не там поставил.

Comment: @Qwertiy дубликат-дубликат. В res гарантированно никогда не будет результата.

Comment: А возможно вывести переменную grantRes за область видимости колбека?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, обоснуй. Помимо того, что написано в первой части моего ответа.

Comment: Проще опишу потребность: есть функция doSQL, принимающая аргументом скрипт и колбек. При вызове в консоль результат из БД получаю. Вопрос: как вызвать doSQL, что б получить результат json в переменную?

Comment: @Qwertiy во-первых, doSQL ничего не возвращает. Во-вторых, запрос в mysql асинхронный и по определению никакого синхронного результата дать не может. Ответ будет в вызове коллбека через какое-то время и точно не в этом «тике»

Comment: @AlexeyTen , что должно в теле  callback(result[0]) что б получить переменную с JSON из БД?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, возвращаемое значение из doSQL нигде не используется, на консоль выводится другое.

Comment: @АнтонМурзинов, я тебе уже ответил, что исправить.

Comment: @Qwertiy *а переменная res == undefined* — т.е. автор таки хочет в `res` видеть результат. Но это невозможно и это дубликат вопроса выше.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, тьфу.. Похоже, мы про разные res говорим. Я вот про этот: `async function(res){` - тут же тоже аргумент res называется. А тот, который снаружи вообще удалить надо.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (err) throw err;  });
> ```

Здесь функция не должна завершаться. И научись нормально форматировать код.

> ```
> var grantRes = await JSON.stringify(res);
> ```

Какая-то абсолютно бесполезная асинхронность...

Comment: По сути мне нужно что б при вызове doSQL с аргументами: sql скрипт и колбек из другого модуля в переменную res попадал json